# Config.ru not found when creating rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to programming, so please be patient.

I was running a rails server yesterday but now I get the following when I attempt to initiate a server:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://O.O.O.O:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
configuration c:/Users/MEdc/desktop/pinteresting/config.ru not found
Exiting
```

ip address above has O in place of 0 for posting

The questions are:
1. Why did the config.ru disappear from my system (search cannot find it);
2. What are the steps to obtain the missing file?

Using Rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.0.0 , Win 7 and only had a single app open in rails.

Comment: Can you fix what you pasted in? It cropped the right half of a bunch of your lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your `config.ru` file would have been removed, but you can download [this file from the Rails GitHub repo](https://raw2.github.com/rails/rails/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config.ru) and save it as `config.ru` in your project's folder.

Comment: For rails 4.0.8 `# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application`